# index out of range google maps android [0... 3] .... because over querying

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

**I am using a Async task to make a request to google server for getting the address details**

```
new LongOperation().execute("");
```

**Inside the async task i am pinging to this url**

```
String url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+latitude+","+longitude+"&sensor=false";
```

### What is happening.::

Sometimes if i make repeated requests to server i get ta JAON Exception as `index out of range google maps android`

### How to resolve this:

- Should i need to put specific delays in requests ? , if so how much
- Or is there any other ways to achieve this and solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The `index out of range google maps` thing happens (probably) because of too fast calls to getJSONFromUrl() function.

Probably 500 ms delay is not enough (I'm assuming you're doing this on a background thread and not Sleeping the UI thread as this is a bad habit). try increasing the delay to something very high, such as a minute (60000 ms) and see if this helps. If it does, lower that number to the lowest one that works.

Comment: @ Psy Duck ...... i also had refered this(http://stackoverflow.com/a/20701512/1083093) answer i need to know the exact the delay possible..... as less as possible would be better or there is any other way to do this method ... because this error randomly takes place

Comment: Its too long right .... i am writing a taxi application so user randomly moves the poi on screen .... there i am picking the credentials .... so it has to be less as possible like 5 sec or less

Comment: Then you need some other approach. What we are doing is not much reliable as it can sometimes work and sometimes won't. Let me check something else.

Comment: Ok ..... I couldn't find a question in stackoverflow ! .... please let me know any similar scenarios others faced in stackoverflow